# InterfaceMetric for "vEthernet (Default Switch)" changes from low priority to high

Tags: windows, networking, hyper-v

## Context

I ran the following yesterday:

```
Get-NetIPInterface | Sort-Object -Property InterfaceMetric | Where-Object ConnectionState -EQ Connected
```

Here was the output:

[image]

Note that the vEthernet entries are all at the bottom with an `InterfaceMetric` of 5000.

Today, the output is:

[image]

Note that the `InterfaceMetric` for `vEthernet (Default Switch)` has changed to 15. It now has the highest priority.

## Questions

Has anyone seen this issue before?

What could be causing the `InterfaceMetric` for `vEthernet (Default Swtich)` to change this way?

I've noticed some DNS resolving issues when connected to VPN and I'm wondering if `vEthernet (Default Switch)` being ahead of everything else might have something to do with it. VPN in this case being *GlobalProtect* by *Palo Alto Networks*.

Note that after I connect to VPN, the IPv4 `Ethernet 3` interface (VPN) is highest priority but the IPv6 `Ethernet 3` interface (VPN) is below `vEthernet (Default Switch)`:

[image]